# Selecting multiple contiguous ranges separately

Tags: excel, range, vba

I'm designing a macro that lets users select certain ranges of a dataset they would like to check for errors (in this case, if respondents to a survey selected the same option for multiple questions). To make it easier for users to see what ranges they are checking (and so VBA can tell which ranges to use), I color code them like so:

```
Set flRange = Application.InputBox("Select the ranges you want to check for flatlining. (To select non-contiguous ranges, hold down CTRL when moving between ranges)", , , , , , , 8)
flRange.Select
flRange.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 222, 117)
```

I then use this color to determine if the range should be analyzed:

```
If Cells(1, x).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 222, 117) Then
```

However, if users select multiple ranges (that should be analyzed separately) that are right next to each other, VBA will read them as part of the same range (since they have the same color).

This is the best way I have figured out to allow users to input multiple non-contiguous ranges to be analyzed with the same method, but I dont know how to solve this issue.  If anyone has a suggestion of how to code this macro better, I would greatly appreciate it.

**Edit: Tim and Joshua solved this. Thanks for the help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cycle through each range separately and explicitly rather than relying on colors to differentiate them.

For example:

```
Sub GetRanges()

    Dim flRange As Range
    'Dim v_Ranges As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    'Tell code to continue if there is an error
    On Error Resume Next

    Set flRange = Application.InputBox("Select the ranges you want to check for flatlining. (To select non-contiguous ranges, hold down CTRL when moving between ranges)", , , , , , , 8)

    'Resume normal error handling
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Check to ensure the range is set
    If flRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Loop through the separate ranges
    For Each rngArea In flRange.Areas
        Debug.Print rngArea.Address
    Next rngArea

End Sub
```

If I run the macro and select cells A1:A8 and cells C4:C13, the output would be:

```
$A$1:$A$8
$C$4:$C$13
```

Without knowing a bit more about specifically what you are doing to each range, I can't dive much deeper, so I will keep it at this general level for now.

I also took the liberty to handle the cancel button for you.  Previously, if a user selected 'Cancel' when the InputBox came up, there would be a VBA error.  This accounts for the error by checking to ensure the range is set before proceeding, and if the range isn't set then the code will exit the subroutine.

Comment: Or loop over using `For Each rng in flRange.Areas` where `rng` will be a `Range` object representing a specific part of the total range.

Comment: I had no idea that even existed.  I don't work with discontinuous ranges often, I've updated my code to incorporate your suggestion.